# React : how to display images from array into carousel with its thumbnail on using react-image-gallery

Tags: json, reactjs, carousel, thumbnails

I am using JSON to display it on my image carousel with its thumbnail but i am facing problem on doing so.

## JSON

```
{
"list": [
{
"RestaurantAttachmentId": "11449",
"RestaurantId": "2384",
"FileName": "classic-hall-ajivasan-banquets.jpg",
"AttachmentType": "3",
"Comments": ""
},
{
"RestaurantAttachmentId": "11449",
"RestaurantId": "2384",
"FileName": "classic-hall-ajivasan-banquets.jpg",
"AttachmentType": "3",
"Comments": ""
}
]
}
```

## JSX

```
class GalleryMain extends Component {
    render() {
        const images = [
      {
        original: 'http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/nature/1/',
        thumbnail: 'http://lorempixel.com/250/150/nature/1/',
      },
      {
        original: 'http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/nature/2/',
        thumbnail: 'http://lorempixel.com/250/150/nature/2/'
      },
      {
        original: 'http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/nature/3/',
        thumbnail: 'http://lorempixel.com/250/150/nature/3/'
      }
    ]

    return (
      <ImageGallery items={images} />
    );
    }
}
```

How to display my images here by mapping.

Any help would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I think are you using react-image-gallery npm right ?

Comment: @Prabhu yes.. please help me to do with my json.

Comment: how did you get the json from GalleryMain component ?

Comment: I am passing it through props.

Comment: this.props.banquetImages it will give me the desired json

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I am facing to map with my json details to display my images there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no image for thumbnail, i have given the only image available for original and thumbnail.
Also assumed that the json object name is 'json'

```
 class GalleryMain extends Component {
        render() {

        let images=this.props.json.list.map((restaurant)=>{ return {original:restaurant.FileName,thumbnail:restaurant.FileName}})
        return (
          <ImageGallery items={images} />
        );
        }
    }
```

Comment: ERROR in ./app/components/venueTemplate/venueTemplateGallary/galleryMain.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , (19:4)

  17 | 
  18 |   let images=banquetSlider.list.map((restaurant)=>({original:restaurant.FileName})
> 19 |     return (
     |     ^
  20 |       <ImageGallery items={images} />
  21 |     );

Comment: Oops.. missed to add the closing paranthesis. Pls try now

Comment: As this var banquet = this.props.banquetSlider; comes with typeof object it gives error of undefined map.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
class GalleryMain extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageList: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    for (var { FileName: url } of this.props.banquetImages.list) {
      var newObj = {}
      newObj.original = url;
      newObj.thumbnail = url;
      this.state.imageList.push(newObj)
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <ImageGallery items={this.state.imageList} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @praabhu thanks but i can't add my json like this this details will come from spi only.

Comment: your json coming from api ?

Comment: this.props.banquetImages will give my desired json in props.

Comment: this.props.banquetImages will give the json right ?

Comment: yes it will give me the desired json in array or obejct

Comment: venueTemplateGallary.js:25195 Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: can you show your code then  only i can understand what is happening